# How to find the lowest power of variable in expression?

Tags: polynomials, filtering, expression-construction

If I have expression like

```
a1/x +a2/x^2 + a3/x^3
```

I want to return 1/x^3. In general case,

```
a1/x +a2/x^2 + a3/x^3 + a4/x^4 .....
```

I will have 1/x^n

Edit:

If I want to print the parameter together, what do I need to do?
like an/x^n?

Comment: have you looked at documentation for `Exponent`? It seems you can get what you want using the code below or a variant thereof (depending on how you want to handle coefficients). `In[1901]:= x^Exponent[a/x + b/x^2 + c/x^3, x, Min]

Out[1901]= 1/x^3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
exp=a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3;   
v=Min@Cases[exp, Power[_, x_?NumberQ] :> x, -1];
Cases[exp, Times[x_, Power[_, v]], -1]
```

Comment: I apologize for asking more question, I forgot to include in the question. If I want to print with the parameter a3/x^3, What would I do?

Comment: @SaesunKim see update. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can get all the informations you want in a list, Then to pick the min. It will be the first. The largest is at the end.

```
expr = a1/x + a2/x^2 + a3/x^3 + a4 x^5 + x^6;
r = {Coefficient[#, x, Exponent[#, x]], #, Exponent[#, x]} & /@ (List @@ expr)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get the answer you want, now simply pull the second entry in the first cell

```
 r[[1, 2]]/r[[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!